# Firebase and Webhook integration question

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, webhooks

I am working on a firebase project and want to make the webhook target URL my function. The issue is is that I cannot seem to simply print the contents of the json file on the page when I run the URL in my browser. I know the basics of HTTP on firebase but am looking for something to help further. I either get an empty array or an error that the request could not be handled. I've tried numerous different ways but for simplicity, I will comment out a basic version. Yes, I know this is not even close to correct on this super basic version but I thought rather than post my ridiculous efforts to bypass circular structures and the such, I would let someone else take a swing. Again, my only goal is to simply see the data from the webhook on the page.

```
exports.test = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send(request.body)
});
```

Comment: Can you share the URL that you call? (you can hide the Firebase project id)

Comment: Yes, the url is: “https://europe-west1-<project I’d>-.cloudfunctions.net/<function name>“

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can read the data from the request according to this documentation is doing the following

```js
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    // Reading date format from URL query parameter.
    // [START readQueryParam]
    let format = req.query.format;
    // [END readQueryParam]
    // Reading date format from request body query parameter
    if (!format) {
      // [START readBodyParam]
      format = req.body.format;
      // [END readBodyParam]
    }
    // [START sendResponse]
    const formattedDate = moment().format(`${format}`);
    functions.logger.log('Sending Formatted date:', formattedDate);
    res.status(200).send(formattedDate);
    // [END sendResponse]
  });
});
```

this code is an example of getting the format of a day and send it back to the client.

you can also check the different ways to read information from the HTTP response [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request).

I hopes this help you in your issue